# Mono fails to convert string to double

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspberry-pi2

I've created a little tool which reads the text from a txt file and processed it.

```
string seconds = null;
string temp = null;
double timetaken = 0.0;

seconds = (File.ReadAllText("file.txt"));
temp = seconds.Replace('.', ',');
timetaken = double.Parse(temp);
```

My problem now is that it runs without problems on Windows, but craches on Linux with mono(raspberry-pi2)

The txt file always just contains one line with 11 characters 
for example: `0.080983088`

I know that the problems is `double.Parse`, but I dont know what to do, I already tried `Convert.todouble` and `double.tryparse`, but it didn't help.

[error log](http://pastebin.com/KuGAwfAY)

Comment: Maybe the culture on your Linux box is using periods instead of commas for the decimal separator?  Try not replacing the period with a comma and use the Invariant culture when you parse `double.Parse(seconds, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: double.Parse(seconds, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)works but now it changes "0.080983088" to "80983088", and it uses, and it works with a ","

Comment: If you're still changing the period to a comma then it's just treating the comma as a thousand place separator, which it basically just ignores.  It needs to be a period for the Invariant culture to recognize it as a decimal separator.

Comment: when i use the "." instead of a "," i craches again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timetaken = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDecimal(temp));
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
string value = "3,14";
value = value.Replace(",",".");
double314 = double.Parse(value,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Comment: double314= double.Parse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);